# How to curry multiple parameters with ramda without specifically invoking the return function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

is it possible to create af function with multiple arguments that returns a compose and invoke it automatically with the last argument. see the example below

```
const data = {
  hello: 'world'
}

const propContains = (values, key) => compose(contains(__,values),prop(key))
propContains(['wor','ld'], 'hello')(data) // --> false
propContains(['wor','ld'], 'hello', data) // --> Function

// this is working but don't want to invoke the compose with the last argument
const propContains2 = (values, key, obj) => compose(contains(__,values),prop(key))(obj)
propContains2(['wor','ld'], 'hello', data) // --> false
```

Here is the [Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20hello%3A%20%27world%27%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20propContains%20%3D%20%28values%2C%20key%29%20%3D%3E%20compose%28contains%28__%2Cvalues%29%2Cprop%28key%29%29%0ApropContains%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%27ld%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%29%28data%29%20%2F%2F%20--%3E%20false%0ApropContains%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%27ld%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%20%2F%2F%20--%3E%20Function%0A%0A%2F%2F%20this%20is%20working%20but%20don%27t%20want%20to%20invoke%20the%20compose%20with%20the%20last%20argument%0Aconst%20propContains2%20%3D%20%28values%2C%20key%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20compose%28contains%28__%2Cvalues%29%2Cprop%28key%29%29%28obj%29%0ApropContains2%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%27ld%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%20%2F%2F%20--%3E%20false%20%20)

Comment: why not write a nested function such as `const propContains3 = (values, key, obj) => {const fn = propContains(values, key); fn(obj); return fn;}`

Comment: Why would you do this? btw code is not working, i think you ment to return `fn(obj)`?

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly unclear what you're looking to do.  Here's one version that looks for only a single value:

```
let propContains = curry((value, key, obj) => 
    contains(value, prop(key, obj)));
propContains('wor', 'hello', data); //=> true
propContains('ld', 'hello', data); //=> true
propContains('foo', 'hello', data); //=> false
```

And here's one that checks multiple values, essentially `map`ping over the above:

```
let propContains = curry((value, key, obj) => 
    map(contains(__, prop(key, obj)), value));
propContains(['wor', 'ld', 'foo'], 'hello', data); //=> [true, true, false]
```

And if you want to see if they're all contained, you can do

```
let propContainsAll = curry((value, key, obj) => 
    all(contains(__, prop(key, obj)), value));
propContainsAll(['wor', 'ld'], 'hello', data); //=> true
propContainsAll(['wor', 'ld', 'foo'], 'hello', data); //=> false
```

You could do a similar thing for `any`.

As all of these are curried with Ramda's [`curry`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry), you can choose whether to supply the final parameter on the first call to get the data or to skip it and get back a function.  It's not clear to me if this is what you're looking for, though.

### Update

I was quite confused by the name.  "`propContains`", which to me meant that the value of the property contained something.  Now I see that you really want something I might write as "`propContainedIn`" or some such:

```
// propContainedIn :: [a] -> String -> Object{String: a} -> Bool
const propContainedIn = curry((values, key, obj) => 
    contains(prop(key, obj), values));
propContainedIn(['wor', 'ld'], 'hello')(data) //=> false
propContainedIn(['wor', 'ld'], 'hello', data) //=> false
propContainedIn(['wor', 'ld', 'world'], 'hello', data) //=> true
propContainedIn(['wor', 'ld', 'world'], 'hello')(data) //=> true
```

Although I'm sure that with enough work this could be made points-free, it would surely be much less readable than this, so I don't see the point.

You can see this too on the (updated) **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20hello%3A%20%27world%27%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20propContains%20%3D%20%28values%2C%20key%29%20%3D%3E%20compose%28contains%28__%2Cvalues%29%2Cprop%28key%29%29%0ApropContains%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%27ld%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%29%28data%29%20%2F%2F%20--%3E%20false%0ApropContains%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%27ld%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%20%2F%2F%20--%3E%20Function%0A%0A%2F%2F%20this%20is%20working%20but%20don%27t%20want%20to%20invoke%20the%20compose%20with%20the%20last%20argument%0Aconst%20propContains2%20%3D%20%28values%2C%20key%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20compose%28contains%28__%2Cvalues%29%2Cprop%28key%29%29%28obj%29%0ApropContains2%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%27ld%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%20%2F%2F%20--%3E%20false%20%20%0A%0A%0Aconst%20propContains3%20%3D%20curry%28%28value%2C%20key%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20contains%28value%2C%20prop%28key%2C%20obj%29%29%29%3B%0ApropContains3%28%27wor%27%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20true%0ApropContains3%28%27foo%27%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20false%0A%0Aconst%20propContains4%20%3D%20curry%28%28value%2C%20key%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20map%28contains%28__%2C%20prop%28key%2C%20obj%29%29%2C%20value%29%29%3B%0ApropContains4%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%20%27ld%27%2C%20%27foo%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5Btruue%2C%20true%2C%20false%5D%0A%0Aconst%20propContainsAll%20%3D%20curry%28%28value%2C%20key%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20all%28contains%28__%2C%20prop%28key%2C%20obj%29%29%2C%20value%29%29%3B%0ApropContainsAll%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%20%27ld%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20true%0ApropContainsAll%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%20%27ld%27%2C%20%27foo%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20false%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20propContainedIn%20%3A%3A%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20String%20-%3E%20Object%7BString%3A%20a%7D%20-%3E%20Bool%0Aconst%20propContainedIn%20%3D%20curry%28%28values%2C%20key%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20contains%28prop%28key%2C%20obj%29%2C%20values%29%29%3B%0ApropContainedIn%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%20%27ld%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%29%28data%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20false%0ApropContainedIn%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%20%27ld%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20false%0ApropContainedIn%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%20%27ld%27%2C%20%27world%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%2C%20data%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20true%0ApropContainedIn%28%5B%27wor%27%2C%20%27ld%27%2C%20%27world%27%5D%2C%20%27hello%27%29%28data%29%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20true%0A%0A)**.

Comment: Hey Scott, Thx for your answer, i was looking for a solution to remove the tail call `const fn = (a,b,c) => compose()(c)` , but i dont think there is a solution to remove it.

Comment: Well, you certainly cannot simply remove it; that's how your function is designed.  But see my update for one designed differently.